# Can't import node-XMLHttpRequest into Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, require

I'm trying to use the Codebird.js library (for Twitter) server-side, using Node.js.
Codebird.js uses the browser supplied XMLHttpRequest object, which Node doesn't have.

Rather than refactoring Codebird.js to use Node's HTTP object, I'm instead trying to import this XMLHttpRequest 'emulation' (if you will);
https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest

The importing `codebird.js` and to-be-imported `xmlhttprequest.js` files are right next to eachother, yet the example on the github for importation fails;

[image: codebird folder]

[image: error]

I have tried importing in all of the following ways, all of which fail with the same error (with the name of the module it can not find always being exactly the argument to `require`);

```
require("xmlhttprequest")              // their example code
require("./xmlhttprequest")
require("./xmlhttprequest.js")
require("xmlhttprequest.js")
require("./XMLHttpRequest")
require("XMLHttpRequest")
require("./XMLHttpRequest.js")
require("XMLHttpRequest.js")
```

I have not modified the 'XMLHttpRequest.js' file in anyway

I'm using Node.js v0.10.18, on a RedHat Linux 4 server
What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized;
The codebird was being imported into a javascript file one level up. When Codebird calls 'require', it is in the context of the file that called it; one level up from xmlhttprequest.js

Comment: Please have a try with the nightly version that you can find at https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-js/archive/develop.zip (or use `npm install codebird`).